# Element of listView highlight not fully

Tags: android, listview

I try to do simplest listView. I create layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/history_menu_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="60dp" >
</TextView>
```

And ListActivity:

```
public class HistoryMenu extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Edit", "Send" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.history_menu, values);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Element of listView highlight not fully, only where text.
How to fix it?

Comment: Please elaborate more . I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/history_menu_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="60dp" >

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in   `Textview`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/history_menu_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="60dp" />
```

Comment: This's the answer. I add some explanation. Your code : android:layout_width="wrap_content". So the highlight only wrap the text. You change to fill_parent and everything's ok